# One large vector layer or many small layers?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a GeoServer that displays some basic country data for Brazil at a course spatial scale (1:1 million). Now the geography institute (IBGE) is making available the topo sheets at 1:250,000 scale, one shapefile for each of the 548 tiles.

In order to store those data in PostGIS and serve via GeoServer, would I be better of merging all topo sheets into one, or is it better to have each sheet as a separate table in PostGIS?

This, of course, considering that there will be no topology issues with the sheets.

Comment: Will you be accessing this data many times or reading once for each process?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, I'm not the DB expert in our group. The data will be available for other people to look at using GeoServer and also in a WebGIS application we developed, all through WMS.

Comment: It looks like I made the answer too soon.The data is provided as 10 large chunks, not 548 small tiles. So I believe I won't have much trouble putting it on PostGis and into GeoServer

Answer (score 5):

I try to keep data that is of similar features in one table.  For example, all 10 data chunks of roads, merge into a table, all 10 data chunks of watercourses, another table.

I find that trying to manually determine which data to load based on which area you are is too much work and is best left up to the spatial indexes in postgis / geoserver.